# how to define a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this:

```
{
   "info" : { "title" : '123},
   "details": [ {"desc": "d1"}, {"desc": "d2}]
}
```

now I am trying to declare types for this object, here is what I got so far:

```
interface Info {
    "title": string,   
}

interface Detail {
    "desc": string,
}
```

how to define a class that consist Info and array of Detail ? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class MyClass {
  info: Info;
  details: Detail[]
}
```

[More info here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply define it with class keyword.

```
class MyClass {
  info: Info[];
  details: Detail[];

  constructor(obj?: any) {
    if(obj) {
      // initialize objects based on properties
    } else {
      // set default values
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, your response give me a hint, it's almost the same as answer 1, just the info is an array